# How to print out specific object in multidimentional array , scala

Tags: arrays, scala, type-mismatch

I want to print out an element of (string, int) array in scala, but the only thing I get is this error

code below doesn't work:

```
var lib = ("word",2)
> lib: (String, Int) = (word,2)

lib(0)
<console>:9: error: (String, Int) does not take parameters
          lib(0)
             ^
```

this works good, but doesn't fit my requests

```
var lib = Array.ofDim[Any](2,2)
lib(0) = Array("word",2)
lib(0)(0)
>res86: Any = word
```

any suggestions how can I print that element out??

Comment: You are creating a `Tuple2`, in your case access notation is `lib._1` and `lib._2`.

Comment: Down voting because user has not made *any* effort to Google this, if one actually Googled "scala array" or "scala list" its easy to see that is **not** an array.

Comment: okay, actually I have google it, but I had no idea how Tuple2 works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lib` is a tuple. It is a [Tuple2](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Tuple2) because it is composed of 2 elements.

To access elements:

```
var lib = ("word", 2)
println(lib._1)   // word
println(lib._2)   // 2

val (w, n) = lib
println(w)        // word
println(n)        // 2

// for function
iterableOfTuple foreach {tuple => println(tuple._1)}
iterableOfTuple foreach {case (w,n) => println(w)}
```

Comment: ok, how to change the value of tuple's element? like lib(0)._1 = 1010 ?

Comment: @ViktorMusienko You can't. Tuples are immutable and can't be reassigned.